# python string to code for function arg?

Tags: python, string, function, arguments, exec

I have a function names "myfunction". I have a string "a", I need to pass it to "myfunction" so it will give the same result as if my string was a python object name, `myfunction(a)`
So I have

```
def myfunction(var):
    print var
a = 1
mystring = "a"
```

I need to pass "mystring" to "myfuntion" so it will behave as variable "a" was passed to it.
I thought of something like this, but it won't work:

```
myfunction(exec(mystring))
```

PS. Yes, I know of the consequences of exec(), please there is no need to explain that.

Answer (score 4):

It would be `eval()`, not `exec`:

```
myfunction(eval(mystring))
```

Alternatively:

```
myfunction(locals()[mystring])
```

Most probably you have a fundamental design problem if you think you need something like this.

Answer (score 1):

No needs in `exec` or `eval`:

```
>>> def myfunc(var):
...     print globals()[var] * 2
...
>>> a = 12
>>> myfunc('a')
24
```